# How to pass a parameter by reference to a member function of template class?

Tags: c++, templates, pass-by-reference

I have a template class with a constructor which accepts parameter as reference. I'm looking for a way to pass the variable in the caller function.

```
template <typename T>
class Data : public ParentClass
{
    T m_data;
public:
    Data(T & data);
    T data() const;
};

template <typename T>
Data<T>::Data(T & data) : m_data(data)
{}

template <typename T>
T Data<T>::data() const
{
    return m_data;
}

int main()
{
    Data<bool> * d = new Data<bool>(true);
    std::cout << d->data() << std::endl;
}
```

> **Error**: no instance of constructor "Data::Data[with T=bool]"
>   matches the argument list  argument types are: (bool)

Comment: `T & data` -> `const T & data`?

Comment: there is non point sending a bool as `const&` you can't modify and bool is smaller then a pointer

Comment: Thanks for the input. But how to deal if it is not a const?

Comment: Your constructor doesn't attempt to modify the passed in parameter, there is no reason to make the parameter non-`const` (and the parameter "doesn't care" whether the original value was declared `const` or not)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't bind an rvalue (i.e. `true`) to a non-const lvalue-reference (i.e. `bool&`). For example you can't do `bool& b = true;`.

To solve the issue you can change the parameter type to `T` or `const T&`.

Comment: @Rotem Yes, it works. But the implementation needs some adjustments too. I'm not sure it matches OP's intent or not.